# Drag and drop container in desired location

Tags: codenameone

I have been trying to use drag and drop to allow a user to rearrange the order of some containers on display. Because the screen needs to scroll I have used the long press listener of a button to set the container to draggable. Advice from other questions showed that adding a form.pointerPressed(x, y) then a pointerDragged allows the drag to initiate on the long press which works well. So far so good. Code and image below showing the master container in green and all other components in blue.

Form formDnD = new Form("Drag and Drop", new BorderLayout());
formDnD.getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> mainForm.showBack());

```
    Container northcnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Container centercnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    centercnt.setScrollableY(true);
    centercnt.setDropTarget(true);
    Container southcnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    Style a = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Icon");
    FontImage iconDnD = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_DRAG_HANDLE, a, 6);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){

        Container c_Master = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        c_Master.setUIID("GreenCont");
        Container c = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        c.setUIID("MyButtonBlue");
        c_Master.add(c);

        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.setUIID("Icon");
        b1.setIcon(iconDnD);
        c.add(new Label("Label 1"));
        c.add(b1);
        c.add(new Label("Label 2"));
        c.add(new Label("Label 3"));

        b1.addLongPressListener(actionEvent -> {

            c_Master.setDraggable(true);

            int x = actionEvent.getX();
            int y = actionEvent.getY();

            formDnD.pointerPressed(x, y);
            c_Master.pointerDragged(x, y);


        });

        c_Master.addDropListener(actionEvent -> {

            if(c_Master.isDraggable()) {
                c_Master.setDraggable(false);
            }
        });

        centercnt.add(c_Master);

    }
    formDnD.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, northcnt).add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centercnt).add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, southcnt);
    formDnD.show();
```

[image: Drag and drop form]

If the user releases the container in the green area then the container drops in that position. If the user drops the container anywhere in the blue area then nothing is dropped. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example I think `c_Master` needs to be the drop target since you would drop components there in this particular case.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the suggestion however I am not trying to drop components in the green area, the c_Master is the container I'm trying to rearrange.

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Container.java#L3110-L3127) and see if this code is reached? This should work seamlessly.

Comment: Yes this is reached. I dont think I have explained myself well. After long press c_Master (green area) becomes draggable and drags. The problem I have is that drop only works if I release the the c_Master (green area) container on another c_Master (green area). If I release on the blue (which is inside the green area) nothing is dropped.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. It finds the right drop area but it doesn't re-arrange the order of the components which is what you want to do right?
Can you set the green container to have a lead component? (any component within the hierarchy). Would that workaround that problem?

Comment: Using a combination of `setLeadComponent` and `setBlockLead(true)` I was able to get the containers to rearrange. Many thanks as always